# Powershell - Why can't I assign output of Get-StoragePool and Get-VirtualDisk to a variable?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0

I am writing a Powershell script to collect statistics on a couple different things and write to a centralized location.

I tried to do the following:

```
$storage_pool_stats = Get-StoragePool
$virtual_disk_stats = Get-VirtualDisk
```

but the results are **(ObjectId = "{1}\SERVERNAME\root/Microsoft/Windows/Sto...)** instead of the FriendlyName/OperationalStatus/HealthStatus data that is printed to the console when I run "Get-StoragePool"

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The nice table view you see printed in the console by default is controlled by type-specific formatting data (see `Get-FormatData -TypeName 'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#MSFT_VirtualDisk'`). What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My hope is to collect all the data in that table (The output of 'Get-StoragePool', 'Get-VirtualDisk' (and if I can be greedy, 'Get-PhysicalDisk' too), either as one piece or as individual pieces that I can stitch back together, and dump into a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the downvotes are all about. For anybody else looking for the answer, writing to a file with Out-File instead seems to keep the formatting. Example below:

```
$GetPhysicalDisks = Get-PhysicalDisk

$GetPhysicalDisks | Out-File -filepath C:\Utilities\test1.txt
```